# what is the css to hide a certain fieldset of a form

Tags: css

This is the form

```
<form class="fes-ajax-form fes-submission-form" action="" name="fes-submission-form" method="post"><div class="fes-form fes-submission-form-div"><fieldset class="fes-el post_title post_title    ">        <div class="fes-label">
            <label for="fes-post_title">Tiêu đề<span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                <div class="fes-fields">
           <input class="textfield edd-required-indicator" id="post_title" type="text" data-required="1" data-type="text" name="post_title" placeholder="" value="" size="40">
        </div>
        </fieldset><fieldset class="fes-el post_content post_content    ">      <div class="fes-label">
            <label for="fes-post_content">Lời nhắn<span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                <div class="fes-fields">
                        <textarea class="textareafield edd-required-indicator" id="post_content" name="post_content" data-required="1" data-type="textarea" placeholder="" rows="40" cols="10"></textarea>
                    </div>
        </fieldset><fieldset class="fes-el multiple_pricing multiple_pricing    ">      <div class="fes-label">
            <label for="fes-multiple_pricing">Tổng số tiền</label>
                    </div>
                <div class="fes-fields">
            <table class="multiple">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                                                                            <th class="fes-price-column">Amount ($)</th>
                                                                                                                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="fes-variations-list-multiple">
                                    <tr class="fes-single-variation">
                                                <input type="hidden" class="fes-name-value" name="option[0][description]" id="options[0][description]" rows="3" value="">
                                                <td class="fes-price-row">
                                                            <input type="text" class="fes-price-value" name="option[0][price]" id="options[0][price]" value="0.00">
                                                    </td>
                                                                    </tr>
                                        <tr class="add_new" style="display:none !important;" id="multiple"></tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5">
                                                    </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
        </fieldset><fieldset class="fes-submit"><input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="0"><input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="46"><input type="hidden" name="vendor_id" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="action" value="fes_submit_submission_form"><input type="hidden" id="fes-submission-form" name="fes-submission-form" value="b7a358155c"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/tim-yeu-cau/entry/2/"><input type="submit" class="edd-submit blue button" name="submit" value="Submit"></fieldset></div></form>
```

I want to hide the fieldset which has class of `fes-el post_content post_content`

My code is

```
.fes-el post_content post_content {
display:none;
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
.fes-el.post_content.post_content {
    display: none;
}
```

In CSS, you omit spaces between the class names when you're selecting them on the same element. You had also left out the period for the post-content classes.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jspnbx8h/)**